# AtomicBoolean vs Synchronized block, whats the difference

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, boolean, atomic

I am trying to understand the difference between the two following code blocks

```
AtomicBoolean ab = new AtomicBoolean(false);  

using the following to get and set state. .
ab.get();
ab.set(X);

vs. 

private boolean ab = false;
private final Object myboollock = new Ojbect();

public void setAB(boolean state)
{
    synchronized(myboollock)
     {
          ab = state;
     }
}

public boolean getAB()
{
 synchronized(myboollock)
 {
         return ab;
 }
}
```

I need to thread protect a boolean, that is all,  and have 
in the past used the later method,  but would like to start to use Atomic 
objects, (if ) they are safe?,

Comment: How about... reading the javadoc of AtomicBoolean? It describes the guarantees offered and the advantages over synchronization.

Comment: please point me to the java doc that explains "clearly" the advantages of one over the other.  I can't find it in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html

Comment: Look at the javadoc for the package `java.util.concurrent.atomic` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few subtle differences but seen from the outside the two code snippets behave similarly: if you call the `set` method, the change will be visible to other threads calling `get` subsequently.

The main differences are:

- performance: depending on the level of contention, you may get better performance with `synchronized` or `AtomicBoolean`
- atomicity: if at some stage you want to do more than just setting the boolean value, a `synchronized` block will allow you to add instructions atomically but `AtomicBoolean` won't

Answer (score 10):

If *all* you're trying to do is make getting and setting a single `boolean` value atomic, then yes - you can use `AtomicBoolean` instead without any synchronization.

Of course, `synchronized` allows a far wider range of uses, such as performing several actions within the block without losing the lock, or using it for wait/notify. So it's not like `AtomicBoolean` is a *general* alternative to synchronization - but in this case you can use it instead of synchronization.